# Python NameError: name '_key_dawn_events' is not defined, хотя метод существет

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
class MyGame():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        self.ship = Ship(self)
    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    _key_dawn_events(event)
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    _key_up_events(event)
            self.ship.update()
            self.ship.draw_ship()
            pygame.display.flip()

    def _key_dawn_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moveup = True

    def _key_up_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moveup = False


game = MyGame()
game.run_game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При ображении к методам/полям объекта, необходимо использовать
`self`
Т.е.

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._key_dawn_events(event)
```

и т.д.

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin уже. Забыл, что я не на обычном stackexchange

Comment: Не думаю, что ruSO чем то кардильно отличается в данном плане. Просто система автоматически определяет Ваш ответ как низкокачественный и просит участников проверить его.  Аналогичные очереди есть на всех сайтах stackexchange, насколько я знаю...вопрос только в том: успевают ли их разгребать там или нет

Comment: @МихаилРебров я имел в виду, что забыл, что я на русском СО и поэтому ответил на английском. А вы как меня поняли?

Comment: да, был невнимателен. Александр именно об этом написал. Я просто перед этим видел с пяток его сообщений в очереди проверок, в которых он просит оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы и писать комментарии к прилагаемых в ответах коду... и не особо вчитываясь спроецировал ту же ситуацию на этот ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)